# Bind repeater list with enum

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, enums

I have a requirement where when a user clicks on image a list should be shown with checkboxes and all the categories that is present in DB and user should be able to select the checkboxes. How can this be achieved using asp:repeater control? the caegory is a enum type and can have n number of values. In repeater i have added a checkbox and a label; the label should display the category text.

Comment: So - you just want to display a list of checkboxes, each one of which represents a value in an enum ? I can provide an example in C# if that would help, it can definitely be done, sorry I haven't done any VB.NET for several years.

Comment: that should help. I will onvert te code n VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you should add the [Description] attribute to each value in your Enum. This allows you to set proper descriptive text for each value. This attribute is in System.ComponentModel, here's an example: -

```
public enum CalendarShowAsEnum
{
    [Description("None")]
    None = 10,
    [Description("Busy")]
    Busy = 20,
    [Description("Out Of Office")]
    OutOfOffice = 30,
    [Description("On Holiday")]
    OnHoliday = 40
}
```

You then need 2 functions: -

- One function that takes an Enum type and a ListBox/DropDown as parameters, and adds an entry for each Enum into the list
- A helper function that converts the enum into the descriptive title you gave them (example above)

The List function might look as follows (all this is taken from a project I worked on): -

```
    public static void BindNamedEnumList(ListControl    list,
                                         Type           enumerationType)
    {               
        list.Items.Clear();

        Array       array = Enum.GetValues(enumerationType);
        ListItem    item;
        string      name;

        var enumerator = array.GetEnumerator();

        if (enumerator != null)
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                Enum value = enumerator.Current as Enum;
                name = EnumHelper.GetEnumName(value);

                item = new ListItem(name);
                item.Value = Convert.ToInt32(value).ToString();

                list.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

This function takes a Type and a ListControl (which ListBox and DropDownList both inherit from). The Type is the .GetType() of the enum you want to add to the list. Note that it *doesn't* select any values and that it *does* depend on each enum value having a defined integer value. The latter part will help you with selecting individual items.

Note the loop calls `EnumHelper.GetEnumName(value)` - this is the helper function that uses the Description attribute I mentioned at the start. This function looks like: -

```
    public static string GetEnumName(object value)
    {
        string retVal = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            FieldInfo fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
            DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            retVal = ((attributes.Length != 0) ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString());
        }
        catch (System.NullReferenceException)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(retVal))
            {
                retVal = "Unknown";
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

It uses reflection, so you'll need to add an Imports for System.Reflection

To use the list function to bind a set of Enum values to the list, simply call

`{HelperClass}.BindNamedEnumList(myListBox, typeof({MyEnumType})`